# turn day of the year into circle coordinate

Tags: python, geometry

I turn day of the years (1,2...365 and sometime 366) into circle coordinates.
But I get a glitch, at the end/start of a new years... with this code:

```
import math as m
import datetime
import numpy as np

X # is a pandas dataframe loaded
angle_by_day = 365.25/360
radius = 1 # valeur x et y entre -1 et 1
rad_convert = m.pi/180

X['day_circle_x'] = radius *  np.cos(angle_by_day * X['dayofyear'] * rad_convert)
X['day_circle_y'] = radius *  np.sin(angle_by_day * X['dayofyear'] * rad_convert)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(X['day_circle_x'], X['day_circle_y'])
```

[image: plot of one year]

Comment: Don't use `365.25`. Use the actual number of days in the specific year.

Comment: Code seems to be incomplete, the X dictionary is not defined.

Comment: X is a df in this case

Comment: Which are the first and last values of `X['dayofyear']`?

Comment: @Ripi2 1 to 365 and to 366 on the leapyears

Comment: To draw a circle by segments between points,  the first and last points must be the same.

Comment: `angle_by_day` must be `360/365.25`. See, you want to break the full angle (360) into chuncks of size 1 day. So when you ask for a day (say 20) you get the proportional angle: `20/365.25 * 360` Be aware that you go with 365.25 but ask for 365-day

Comment: @Ripi2 you got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ripi2 said,
360/365.25 in lieu of 365.25/360